# Passing file to function to parse

Tags: python, django

I have an upload form that takes a file and sends it to a function to parse. It is a CSV file and im using a DataField type to store it.

views.py

```
def upload(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = CSV(file=request.FILES['csvfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Send file to parser
            import fanduel.load_data
            fanduel.load_data.parse(newdoc.file, request.user)

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app.views.upload'))
    else:
        form = UploadForm()  # A empty, unbound form
```

load_data.py

```
def parse(file, username):
    import csv
    dataReader = csv.reader(open(file), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

forms.py

```
# In forms.py...
from django import forms

class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    csvfile = forms.FileField(
        label='Select a CSV file',
    )
```

models.py

```
class CSV(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='csv/')
```

traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/

Django Version: 1.7.6
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'import_export',
 'app')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Wilson\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Wilson\PycharmProjects\bankroll2\app\views.py" in upload
  20.             app.load_data.parse(newdoc.file, request.user)
File "C:\Users\Wilson\PycharmProjects\bankroll2\app\load_data.py" in parse
  13.     dataReader = csv.reader(open(file), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

Exception Type: TypeError at /app/
Exception Value: invalid file: <FieldFile: csv/app_entry_history_20150316_w62ruKt.csv>
```

I'm not sure how to get it to pass it in as the correct file type. If I enter a filepath manually into load_data.py it works fine, so it's something to do with the way it's passed in.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* your problem is that you are trying to open the wrong filename. When a file is uploaded to a webserver, it is either stored in memory, or written to a temporary location - Django does this as well (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored).

So the value in `request.FILES['csv']` is the location of the temporary file. What you want is the file that gets stored in your forms. You will need to paste your forms and models, but I am guessing the following might work, so instead of this

```
newdoc = CSV(file=request.FILES['csvfile'])
```

you need

```
newdoc = CSV(file=form.cleaned_data['csvfile'])
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using your code but im getting `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'`

Comment: Did you use `request` instead of `form` ?

Comment: Hi, im using the name 'csvfile' in my form, so im assuming thats the correct name. I changed it to form instead of request, but I'm getting the same invalid file error.

Comment: Ohh. Okay, can you try the following - instead of `fanduel.load_data.parse(newdoc.file, request.user)` can you try `fanduel.load_data.parse(newdoc.url, request.user)`

Comment: Thanks :) `'CSV' object has no attribute 'url'` Getting that now